# building a project in emacs

Tags: emacs, ide, compilation, build-process, build-automation

I'm  new to emacs and I'm trying to make it work as an IDE like code blocks which I've been using quite a lot so i downloaded and installed the cedet package and SrSpeedbar but I have no clue how to build a project in emacs the same way codeblocks or other IDEs do. so any link to a package that does that or a easy method would be very helpful. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the EDE package in the CEDET, that provides some functionality for building projects, but this depends on which language & build tool you're using.  If you're build tool isn't supported directly by EDE, you can still use `ede-generic-project`, and specify compilation command in project's local variables - see EDE information on more details.

You can find some information for start in [my article on CEDET](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe take a look at:

1. emake: https://github.com/proofit404/EMake
2. quickrun: https://github.com/syohex/emacs-quickrun

Currently I'm not using cedet and these two packages, but hope that help.